# findViewByID Relative Layout in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-relativelayout

In my XML, I have a Linear Layout that contains two Relative Layouts (one on top, one on bottom). The bottom Relative Layout contains a ViewFlipper, which I want to use to show images. Right now, I'm trying to place these images in a filelist in Java so I can access them in a 'for loop', if that makes sense. I'm trying to define the bottom Relative layout in Java, so that I can put the ViewFlipper in it. When I try to use findViewByID, the ID I created for the layout (in XML) doesn't pop up as an option. 
Am I going at the process the right way or is there another way I can try?
This is that part of the Java code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
brl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.);
vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.Flipper);
```

My XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Analysis"
    android:id="@+id/mainLL" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:id="@+id/topRL" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewFilename"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Filename"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="35dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewSpecies"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewFilename"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Frog Species"
            android:textSize="40dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextLocation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSpecies"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="What is your location?" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonSave"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="SAVE" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/bottomRL" >

        <ViewFlipper
            android:id="@+id/Flipper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true" >
        </ViewFlipper>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.mylayout); //missing
              brl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Relativelayout);

Comment: Maybe. one thing you should know is that findViewById only find CHILD views. So is R.id.Flipper a child of the view which runs the java code above?

Comment: Post the xml. In there you are missing the setcontentview with the layout.

Comment: @MTilsted The Flipper is a child of the Relative Layout, which is a child of the Linear Layout

Comment: Can you provide the XML file? By looking at your code, I can't see the id of your layout

Comment: There you go. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the method `setContentView(int resId)` is missing; so you are trying to find a `View` from a ***null Content*** , that's why it will give you a `NullPointerException`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // IMPORTANT : set a content layout to your activity before retreiving any view
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        brl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.);
        vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.Flipper);
}
```

Comment: I added setContentview, but the ID for the Relative Layout still does not pop up as an option. however, by your answer, can I safely assume that it IS possible to use findViewByID for a layout?

Comment: in the `setContentView()`method, you should pass the name of your layout as an id (ex : `setContentView(R.layout.your_xml_file_name);` ) , and in your Activity  , you can retreive your Layout by its id using findViewById() method ( ex : `RelativeLayout topRL = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.topRL);`)